# Laravel Join returns empty array

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, inner-join, laravel-8

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('course', 'users.id', '=', 'course.courseId')
    ->join('skills', 'users.id', '=', 'skills.id')
    ->join('subjects', 'users.id', '=', 'subjects.id')
    ->get();
 dd($users);
```

This gives me an empty result like this- `items: []`. I would like to join the 4 tables - `users`, `course`, `skills` & `subjects` and fetch all the data in all the 4 tables. `users` table has the id column(PK) named as `id`, `course` table has the id column(PK) named as `courseId`,  `skills` table has its id column(PK) named as `id` & `subjects` table also has the id column(PK) named as `id`. The PK of all 4 tables is of the same data type biginteger. How to solve this?

Comment: do `leftJoin` instead of `join` or make sure you have data in all tables. Using relation would be easier if all you want is get all data (check answer)

Comment: @N69S All the 4 tables have data

Comment: Each user need to have data in all 4 tables, or do left joins. From documentation `to perform a basic "inner join", you may use the join method`. With inner join, if there is no row linked to one of the user in one of the other tables, the user will not be present in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the relations to get all the data:

The `User::class` has three relation methods `hasMany()` to the other classes (`Course::class`, `Skill::class` and `Subject::class`)

```
$users = User::with(['courses', 'skills', 'subjects'])->get();
```